# Why has my Symfony web server stopped responding but apache is fine after updates?

Tags: php, localhost, symfony

I was notified for regular ubuntu updates today and since then, when I start and stop the Symfony development server with:

```
php bin/console server:start
php bin/console server:stop
```

I receive the usual corresponding notifications:

> [OK] Stopped the web server listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000
>
> [ERROR] No web server is listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000

**However**, when I go to `localhost:8000/` as usual, firefox just returns

> Unable to connect

If I try localhost through Apache (on `localhost/` it works without problem.

When I check the version of PHP I'm running it returns:

```
PHP 5.5.35-1+donate.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) (built: May  4 2016 12:32:19)
```

Does anyone know what has happened to stop it working? It has been working fine for the last couple of months without problem.

**UPDATE:**
Following the helpful comments from Drmjo, below are the latest entries in `/var/logs/dev.log`:

```
[2016-05-05 20:47:03] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". [] []
[2016-05-05 20:47:03] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onCommand". [] []
[2016-05-05 20:47:03] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onCommand". [] []
[2016-05-05 20:47:03] php.DEBUG: fsockopen(): unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8000 (Connection refused) {"type":2,"file":"/home/me/projects/myproject/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/ServerCommand.php","line":59,"level":28928} []
[2016-05-05 20:47:03] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
[2016-05-05 20:47:03] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onTerminate". [] []
[2016-05-05 20:47:03] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onTerminate". [] []
```

Comment: is a process already bound to port 8000??

Comment: I'm pretty certain there isn't (although is there a way I can check to confirm?) as I was using the symfony server fine this morning - just once ubuntu started the regular updates it stopped working in the middle of whichever updates being installed (looking at my PHP version dated 4th May I'm assuming it was that?)

Comment: ```sudo netstat -tpln``` will give you the answer... if you are on 14.04 or lower... if you are using the new ones its ```sudo ss -tpln```... that will list all the programs listening on all the TCP ports

Comment: Thanks @Drmjo - I've made a note of that command! :) Unfortunately there's nothing on port 8000 though

Comment: does anything pop up in app/logs/dev.log or prod.log... depending on your environment??

Comment: I've updated the question with the latest records in the `dev.log` - I'm still getting my head around Symfony so it unfortunately doesn't make things any clearer to me - thanks in advance if you can give any insight! :)

Comment: well.. .i was able to duplicate the unable to connect error but  it looks like the prosess does actually bind to port 8000 because its not an error its a warning... and ```curl localhost:8000``` does return a page from symfony... try running the command ```php bin/console server:start &``` then run netstat to see if it's binding or just giving you a warning...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111158/discussion-between-bendy-and-drmjo).

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue recently.

I don't how to stop this from happening but stopping the server,
executing "php bin/console cache:clear"

and then starting the server again with "php bin/console server:run" made it work again.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The clue was in the ubuntu updates. I'd modified some of the php config files (in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d) and the ubuntu update, for me, had added 20-apcu.ini and 20-xdebug.ini soft links and one of them had broken the command line PHP sufficiently that Symfony just seemed to hang.

Delete them and you should be good to go.